# Noob question - Link multiple urls to single Word with <a href>, is possible?

Tags: html, url, browser, href

I want to know if it's possible to link a single word to multiple page for example:

word 1 have to be linked to multiple urls so when you click it, multiple bars will be open on your browser.

i'm new to HTML programming, i know that  word 1  is the command to link 1 url to a word; I want to be something like this  word 1 .

is possible or not? if not there is a way to do it.

Thank you all for your time and help.
Mark

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Is not clear what are you asking

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: clarification

correction in the line "I'm new to HTML programming.. i know that i can connect 1 word to 1 url with command <a href " url1">, i want to make something like this <a href "url 1" "url 2" url 3" (and so on) word 1 </a>.

Comment: yes i'm sorry the html commands were deleted in the question so it's not clear i  made some clarification above

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://yourwebsite.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://yourwebsite.com/hello.html'); window.open('http://yourwebsite.com/contact.html');window.open('http://yourwebsite.com/mysite.html');">Word 1</a>
```

If i understood correctly this should solve your problem and also, try explaining your problem better and maybe give a part of your code.

Comment: hi Snakeing,

I havn't a full html yet because i can't figure out how to do this passage.

i write down with the links

Comment: UPDATE.

it works, it didn't before because i used opera web browser wich have and integrated pop-up block that block the urls after the "window open" command.

thank you for your help and time Snakeing.